# Resttemplate url response giving Invalid mime type

Tags: java, spring

I am callling a url like below , but in the response i am getting the Invalid mime type "JSON; charset=utf-8": does not contain '/'

```
   @RequestMapping("/")
       public String hello(){

           HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
           UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://XXXX/Query.ashx");
           HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
           RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
           HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                   builder.toUriString(),
                   HttpMethod.GET,
                   entity,
                   String.class);

           return  response.getBody() ;
       }
```

From  postman i checked the response headers  of the api , there we are getting Content-Type : JSON; charset=utf-8 , which i am getting here . How to handle this ?, we we just want plain json response.

Answer (score 0):

Use '@RestController' annotation

Answer (score 0):

@Himanshu Kindly provide complete class information which contain class level annotations. Along with that question is **Are you getting exception while calling shown api or restTemplate.exchange?**. Update your answer with complete stacktrace to find that.

I would prefer to use **@GetMapping** which is default to Json Response. Please try that

Answer (score 0):

You can completely control request/response parameters using RestTemplate interceptor(s):

```
public class MimeInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body,
            final ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.<what you want>);
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.<what you want>);
        return response;
    }
}
```

And in code:

```
...
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setInterceptors(List.of(new MimeInterceptor());
...
```